# SonarQube Eclipse plugin associates with wrong project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sonarqube

Environment:

- Eclipse Luna 4.4.0
- SonarQube 4.3.1
- SonarQube Eclipse plugin 3.4.0.20140404-0949-RELEASE
- Windows 7 and Mac OSX 10.9.4

On the SonarQube server, I have several projects which are already analyzed. Most of them are in Java, and I used Maven to analyse them. All of them have the same groupId (`com.mycompany`) but a different artifactId (`productname`). The project keys in SonarQube are thus `com.mycompany:productfoo`, `com.mycompany:productbar`, etc.

I have installed and configured the SonarQube Eclipse plugin, as described in the documentation. Connection with the server was tested.
I have checked out the Maven projects from source control.
I was able to associate most Eclipse projects with the corresponding SonarQube project.

However, for one project, when I try to associate it, the plugin always associates it with the wrong project. It does not matter if I enter the product name or the product key in the search box.

I associated with the wrong project anyway, closed Eclipse and then edited `.settings/org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core.prefs`: I changed the value of `projectKey` to the correct value (`com.mycompany\:productbaz`). If I then restart Eclipse and run an analysis, it seems to work.

So my question is: How can I associate with the right project, without needing to manually edit the prefs file?